# Java - Counting how many times an integer appears in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I need to find how many times a certain integer appears in a matrix and whatever I do, the result I get is always "0". Most probably the answer is simple, but I just can't find it, and I would appreciate some help. :)

This is my code:

```
    int m, n, c, d, nr = 0, x;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows:");
    m = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns:");
    n  = in.nextInt();

    int matrix[][] = new int[m][n];

    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix:");

    for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
        for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
            matrix[c][d] = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the value for number x:");
    x = in.nextInt();

    for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ) {
        if(c == x)
            nr++;
    }

    for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ) {
        if(d == x)
            nr++;
    }

    System.out.println("Number x appears " + nr + " times.");`
```

P.S. I'm pretty new to Java.

Comment: You are not accessing your matrix "matrice" at any time when you check  (I guess the checks are the final two loops). You will need to transverse it exactly the same way you are populating it (two nested for loops)

Comment: Hi Daniel, i see that problem cames because you are not searching in the matrix! Try to think a little more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You weren't comparing your `matrice` with `x`.

You were comparing `x` with the index.

Instead try this:

```
for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ) {
    for(d = 0; d < n; d++) {
        if(x == matrice[c][d]) {
            nr++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Number x appears " + nr + " times.");`
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the values of the matrix like this

```
for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ) {
    for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ) {
        if(matrix[c][d] == x)
            nr++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write instead:

int m, n, c, d, nr = 0, x;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of rows:");
m = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the number of columns:");
n  = in.nextInt();

int matrix[][] = new int[m][n];

System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix:");

for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
    for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
        matrix[c][d] = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the value for number x:");
x = in.nextInt();

//MODIFY THIS:

for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
    for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
        if (matrix[c][d] ==x)
              nr++;


System.out.println("Number x appears " + nr + " times.");`
```

The reason is that you want to pass on all the cells in the matrix and check which one of them equal to x.

Answer (score 1):

You have to test the content of the matrix, instead of the indices:

```
for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; ++r)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < matrix.length; ++c)
    {
        if (matrix[r][c] == x)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a nested for setup something like

```
for(small to large x){
   for(small to large y){
      if(matrix[x][y] == integer looking for)
          count = count + 1; }}
```

This would be done after your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    for (  c = 0 ; c < matrix.length ; c++ ) {
         for ( d = 0 ; d < matrix[c].length ; d++ ) {
                if(matrix[c][d] == x)
                    nr++;
            }

    }
```